# Accessing Value of Textarea After Form Submission

Tags: php, html, text, area

After I submit my form I try to get the value of my text area using the command:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

However, it cannot find the value of this text area. I suspect it is because it is not an input. How can I access the value of this text area after a form submission?

```
<textarea rows = "12" cols = "43" 
   input id = "message" placeholder = "Message:" class = "textbox">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Add this attribute: `name="message"`.

Comment: ^--« Wait for the answers to **roll in like oranges** »--v Sam hit the nail right on the head. +1

Answer (score 0):

The textarea needs a `name` attribute, like this:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="12" cols="43" id="message" placeholder="Message:" class="textbox"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in the POST variable corresponds to the textarea's name attribute, not it's id: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp. In fact, the value from the textarea will not even be passed to the action page without a name attribute:

> Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values
>   passed when submitting a form.

So, first add `name="message"` to the textarea. Then you will be able to access the value of the textarea after form submission with `$_POST['message']` (assuming your form has `method="post"`).